# top / htop for GPU?

Tags: performance, graphics, gpu, macos

I have been having some of the worst performance problems with my Mac Pro that I've ever seen.  It seems to start at the darnedest times with no apparent provocation.  I've poured through everything from many and varied `dtrace` scripts to other dark arts incantations to no avail.

I was working away when I popped up to iStat Menus for a peak at what might be consuming my processors during a particularly grueling moment and noticed that my GPU was not only peaked out, but that it has been consistently peaked out for a VERY long time:
[image: GPU Usage Graph]

Not only is this interesting, but performance problems also coincide with these periods of time.  I now have a fair amount of certainty that there is some culprit chewing on my GPU for obscene amounts of time and this would explain a lot of various problems that occur with screen redraw, input, etc. ad infinitum.

Any ideas on any tools or methods to track down such problems on an ATI card?

Comment: Do you have anything in the Console report at the times of the event?

Comment: @Buscar웃 unfortunately not. This is something that is expressing itself in any of the logs that I have dug through.

Comment: After 6 years. Have you found anything good?

Answer (score 1):

*Activity Monitor* may be able to help you out. It has 2 columns, called `%GPU` and `GPU Time`, which both can be used to track down the process causing problems.

If you don't see the columns, just simply go on `View`, in the menu bar, then `Columns` and selected the aforementioned columns to show them. [image: Activity Monitor example]

Comment: There is also a command line tool called [`asitop`](https://github.com/tlkh/asitop), which however does not work on MacOS13 Ventura (but a fix should come soon enough).